# Cannot show date picker over bottom sheet

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show `DatePicker` over `BottomSheet` and I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart':
Failed assertion:
line 1557 pos 10: '!barrierDismissible || barrierLabel != null': is not true.
```

Here is my code:

```
  Future<DateTime> _selectDate(context) async {
    return await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2018),
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you share the code that you use to show picker?

Comment: sure, post updated

Answer (score 1):

BottomSheet class required a WidgetBuilder (means you need a widget)
but showDatePicker() doesn't provide any Widget.

If you need a date picker on BottomSheet. I prefer using the Cupertino DatePicker.

Example here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_picker_demo.dart

Comment: If Material style is needed what is the solution?

Comment: Shouldn't wrapping the date-picker in a Material widget( e.g. Card) help this?

Comment: I think custom widget is only solution.

Comment: Is any solution with a material style calendar on bottom sheet?

Answer (score 0):

User StatefulBuilder() to fix it. I just give another example like as datepicker

```html
  showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    bool b = false;
                    return StatefulBuilder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, setState) => Column(
                        children: [
                          Switch(
                            onChanged: (bool v) {
                              setState(() => b = v);
                            },
                            value: b,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
```